# Android: Why intent doesn't received by broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a few intents that activity sends to service.
All of those are registered in manifest:

```
<service android:name=".location.LocationService" android:label="@string/location_service_started">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="@string/location_service_set" />
                        <action android:name="@string/location_service_start" />
                        <action android:name="@string/location_service_stop" />             
                    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But only location_service_start and location_service_stop intents are received. What could be the reason?
There is my receiver code:

```
private BroadcastReceiver LocationServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(getString(R.string.location_service_stop)))
        {
            showMessage("stop");    
        }
        if(intent.getAction().equals(getString(R.string.location_service_start)))
        {
            showMessage("start");
        }   
        if(intent.getAction().equals(getString(R.string.location_service_set)))
        {
            showAlertBox("set");    
            
        }
    }
};
```

So I never see "set" message. I've even tried put sendBroadcast for "start" and "set" messages in the same place, but everything still the same. "start" - OK, "set" - never received.

Functions that fires intents:

```
protected void start()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getString(R.string.location_service_start));
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

protected void set(double lat, double lon, double rad)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getString(R.string.location_service_set));
        intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
        intent.putExtra("lon", lon);
        intent.putExtra("rad", rad);
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Both are correct send, without errors, actions are correct.

---

> UPD:
>
> Oh, my fault. I forgot to add filter.addAction... for new intent.
> I'm sorry. But answers was really useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All of those are registered in manifest:

Generally, you do not use string resources for action strings in an `<intent-filter>`, because you never want to internationalize them.

Generally, you do not use an `<intent-filter>` at all with a service unless you are exposing that service to third-party apps. In fact, right now, you *are* exposing your service to third-party apps, so anyone can send these commands to your service.

> But only location_service_start and location_service_stop intents are received

No, none of them are received by the service. You are sending broadcasts in the Java code. Services do not receive broadcasts.

> Functions that fires intents:

Do not use `getApplicationContext()` unless you know what you are doing. Whatever you are calling `getApplicationContext()` on *is* a `Context`, so you can just call `sendBroadcast()` on it.

Comment: Thank you. It's useful. And  I know that not service but broadcast receiver which is registered in service receives intents. But it doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: "Do not use getApplicationContext() unless you know what you are doing" - Isn't it better to use getApplicationContext() for broadcast that scopes beyond the current Activity? I think that the Activity will not be recycled while broadcast is not complete, but seeing your comment I'm less sure. Can you comment?

Comment: @uval: "Isn't it better to use getApplicationContext() for broadcast that scopes beyond the current Activity?" -- no. "I think that the Activity will not be recycled while broadcast is not complete" -- the broadcast will be "complete" in microseconds, from the standpoint of the broadcaster. All framework-level broadcasts (e.g., `sendBroadcast()`) involve IPC. So, the `Context` sends the broadcast request to a core OS process, at which point the `Context`'s work is done.

Answer (score 1):

*Copy & Paste from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983686/problem-in-geting-click-event-in-clickable-widget) I just answered. Should be the same issue.*

You have to put each `<action />` tag inside a seperate `<intent-filter />` tag in your manifest.

This should be a bug, since the doc states you can put more than one action inside a filter tag:

> Zero or more action [..] tags should be included
>   inside to describe the contents of the filter.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestIntentFilter)