# Problem in geting click event in Clickable Widget

Tags: android, widget

I have written a click-able widget. I can see the widget. But I cann't detect click event in that widget. If I click on the widget then onReceive method should be called. but its not getting called. Can anyone guide me what may be the problem.

### Source Code

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static int IDs[];
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        System.out.println("...inside receive11....");

        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.NEXT_CLICK")) {
            System.out.println("Back Button Clicked ::::::::::::  ");

            onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), IDs);
            // views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                "com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.NEXT_CLICK_NEXT")) {
            System.out.println("Onion Button Clicked Button:::::::::::: ");

            onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), IDs);
            // views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        }
        if (intent.getAction()
                .equals("com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.TEXTVIEW_CLICK")) {
            System.out.println("Next Button Clicked ::::::::::::  ");

            onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), IDs);
        }
        System.out.println("...out to receive11....");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        IDs = appWidgetIds;
        this.context = context;
        System.out.println("...inside update....");
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.mywidget);

        Intent buttonPrevious = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        buttonPrevious.setAction("com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.NEXT_CLICK");
        PendingIntent pendingIntentButtonP = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, buttonPrevious, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.mywidget_left,
                pendingIntentButtonP);

        Intent buttonMiddle = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        buttonMiddle.setAction("com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.TEXTVIEW_CLICK");
        PendingIntent pendingIntentButtonM = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, buttonMiddle, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.mywidget_middle,
                pendingIntentButtonM);

        Intent buttonNext = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        buttonNext.setAction("com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.NEXT_CLICK_NEXT");
        PendingIntent pendingIntentButtonN = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, buttonNext, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.mywidget_right,
                pendingIntentButtonN);


    }
}
```

### In Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".MyWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.NEXT_CLICK" />
                <action android:name="com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.NEXT_CLICK_NEXT" />
                <action android:name="com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.TEXTVIEW_CLICK" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" android:process=":remote" />
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgot to update the widget in onUpdate() method.

write `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);` at the end of onUpdate() method

Answer (score 0):

You have to put each `<action />` tag inside a seperate `<intent-filter />` tag in your manifest.

This should be a bug, since the doc states you can put more than one action inside a filter tag:

> Zero or more action [..] tags should be included
>   inside to describe the contents of the filter.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestIntentFilter)